# React set state condition (if else or ternary) not working. (working even if false)

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, react-hooks, conditional-statements, state

I'm making a job list challenge in React.

I'm trying to add a filter to show only some properties according our choice.

The goal is to click on one of the component situated on the right.(See attached picture)
This component will be showed in the top bar to know on which one we clicked.
Here, it's "Frontend".
As you can see, there are multiple "Frontend" in the top bar because I clicked on it multiple time

[Browser picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv2LG.jpg)
Deployed on vercel here https://static-job-list-in-react.vercel.app/

I'm trying to make a condition to avoid that.

For that, I created a hook with [onFilter, setOnFilter]

But no matter the way i'm trying, the if else statement isn't working.

```
const Container = () => {

    const[onFilter, setOnFilter] = useState([]);
    /*const[word, setWord] = useState([]);*/

    const onClickBtn = (e) => {

        let ok = onFilter.indexOf(<span className="filtered">{e.target.innerText}</span>);
        const update = [...onFilter, <span className="filtered">{e.target.innerText}</span>];

        if(ok===-1){
            setOnFilter(update)
        }
        
        
            }

    return (
        
        <div className="container">
        <div className="filter">
        {onFilter.map(e=> e)}
            <button className="clear">
            
            Clear
            </button>
        </div>
            <Card datas={Datas} onClickBtn={onClickBtn}/>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Github repo here https://github.com/AnthoVDO/Front_End_Mentor--Challenge/blob/master/static-job-listings-react/src/components/Container.js

I tried to write the function like 5 to 6 different way.

I read the documentation and even with that, I don't understand.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not paste screenshots of your code. Instead, edit your question by adding it as a formatted code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that `<span className="filtered">{e.target.innerText}</span>` gets transformed into an object and can't therefore be compared with `indexOf` (as your are comparing the reference of the object).

The solution is to only store the name of your filter in your state since it's a string that can be compared by value with `indexOf`, and write your `<span>` in the `map` function.

```js
import React from "react";
import Card from "./Card";
import Datas from "../data.json";
import { useState } from "react";

const Container = () => {
  const [onFilter, setOnFilter] = useState([]);
  /*const[word, setWord] = useState([]);*/

  const onClickBtn = (e) => {
    let ok = onFilter.indexOf(e.target.innerText);

    if (ok === -1) {
      setOnFilter((previousFilter) => [...previousFilter, e.target.innerText]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="filter">
        {onFilter.map(filter => (
          <span className="filtered" key={filter}>
            {filter}
          </span>
        ))}
        <button className="clear">Clear</button>
      </div>
      <Card datas={Datas} onClickBtn={onClickBtn} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Container;
```